# Windows Server 2003 на вируталке, Active Directory - не загружается

Tags: active-directory, virtual, windows-server

Установил WS 2003 на Virtualbox, настроил AD, но после перезагрузки лишь виден один курсор на черном фоне, система больше ни на что не реагирует. Пробовал под VM Ware, рез-т тот же. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

А если не настраивать АД, то нормально перезагружается? Очень похоже на ошибки инициализации системы, маловероятно, но может хост система не в порядке(видео/память)

Answer (score 0):

Опишите более подробно, как хост-систему так и виртуалку. какие параметры задаете? Включен ли в биос параметр виртуализации на процах Интел? Предоставлена ли процессорная виртуализация вииртуал-системе? ну и т.п. - подробности в студию